# How to ignore the error of the typings folder?

Tags: json, angular, typescript-typings

I added `mongoose` and also its typings.

When I `npm run watch`, I got the error in my terminal:

> ERROR in /my-project/typings/globals/mongoose/index.d.ts (5,28): error
>   TS2307: Cannot find module 'mongodb'.
>
> ERROR in /my-project/typings/globals/mongoose/index.d.ts (2071,32):
>   error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MongoosePromise'.

I changed my **tsconfig.json** "exclude" part to

```
  "exclude": [
    "typings/main.d.ts",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/globals/mongoose/index.d.ts",
    "node_modules"
  ],

  "exclude": [
    "typings/main.d.ts",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/globals/mongoose",
    "node_modules"
  ],

  "exclude": [
    "typings/main.d.ts",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/globals",
    "node_modules"
  ],
```

Neither of above works.

And if I change to

```
  "exclude": [
    "typings",
    "node_modules"
  ],
```

It will give me MORE errors (several pages).

How to ignore the error in the typing folder? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be:

1. Make sure mongodb and node definitions installed:

   typings install dt~node dt~mongodb --global
2. Use the promise library

   mongoose.Promise = your_promise

If you're using the default mpromise, you should:

```
typings install dt~mongoose-promise --global
```

You can find out more at [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3949)

Hop this help!